# How to return all the Objects that have their IDs inside a List of Long

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list of Long values as follow :-

```
List<long> relatedUserID = new List<long>() ;
```

But how i can retrieve all entity framework objects that have their ID inside the List. i am trying to write something such as :-

```
return entities.User.Where(a=>a.UserID.contain(relatedUserID)).Include(a2=>a2.UserDetails);
```

can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check wheter `relatedUserID` contains `UserID`, so you got it in wrong way.
Replace

```
Where(a=>a.UserID.contain(relatedUserID))
```

with

```
Where(a => relatedUserID.Contains(a.UserID))
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have it reversed.  The list isn't contained in the long, the long is contained in the list.

```
return entities.User.Where(a=>relatedUserID.Contains(a.UserID))
    .Include(a2=>a2.UserDetails);
```